# Alter :path_prefix dynamically when calling has_attachment via Attachment Fu plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attachment-fu

By default [Attachment Fu](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/attachment_fu) stores uploaded files in `"public/#{table_name}"`. I want to modify this to be something like `"public/#{table_name}/#{site_id}"`, where `site_id` is a property of the model. Note that I've tried using `self.site_id` and both fail.

```
has_attachment :storage => :file_system, 
               :max_size => 25.megabytes,
               :path_prefix => "public/#{table_name}/#{site_id}",
               :thumbnails => { 
                 :large => '256x256>', 
                 :medium => '128x128>', 
                 :small => '64x64>' 
               }
```

I receive "undefined local variable or method site_id" error messages. Removing the `#{site_id}` component from the `:path_prefix` works fine and the `initialize` method is run. I can access the `site_id` as expected.

I have an `initialize` method which looks like this:

```
def initialize(site_id = nil)
  super(nil)
  self.site_id ||= site_id
end
```

I instanciate the object via the Rails console like this:

```
r = Resource.new(100)
```

Is the `has_attachment` method running before my `initialize` method? How can I pass a parameter into the `:path_prefix` dynamically when the model is instantiated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`site_id` is a dynamic value, so you can't set this in the class. You'll want to redefine #full_filename in your model.  The current definition looks like:

```
def full_filename(thumbnail = nil)
  file_system_path = (thumbnail ? thumbnail_class : self).attachment_options[:path_prefix].to_s
  File.join(RAILS_ROOT, file_system_path, *partitioned_path(thumbnail_name_for(thumbnail)))
end
```

Change the final line to something like:

```
File.join(RAILS_ROOT, file_system_path, site_id.to_s, *partitioned_path(thumbnail_name_for(thumbnail)))
```